# Selenium unable to identify onclick Javascript code

Tags: javascript, selenium, onclick, webdriver, element

![enter image description here][1]I have a dropdown element which is not identified by selenium webdriver and the following is the code for it. I need to click on id=lnkMenu1 which then opens the drop down and then click on `id="lnkMenu2_ul".` But selenium is not identifying. I tried Actions commands and Css selector, xpath none of them works.

```
<div class="nestedMenuDiv">
<a id="lnkMenu1" class="" onclick="javascript:parentClick('lnkMenu1'); return false;" href="#">Wireless & Alerts</a>
</div>
<ul id="entMenu1_2" style="left: 107px; top: 21px; display: none;">
<div class="nestedMenuDiv">
```

Dropdown to click

```
<a id="entMenu1_2" target="bodyFrame" href="#" onclick="navClick('Alerts.Retail.AdHoc','entMenu1_2',1, ''); return false">FidConnect</a>
</li>
```

I am getting `no such element found` error

The following is the complete HTML code. Please suggest me how do I go about it

```
<html>
<head>
<frameset border="0" frameborder="no" rows="100%, *">
<frame marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="NO" src="main.do?browserOK=Y" name="mainframe">
<html>
<head>
<frameset border="0" frameborder="no" rows="100%, *">
<frame marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="NO" src="main.do?browserOK=Y" name="mainframe">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Alpha - ECA Web Portal</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link href="../theme/styles/nav_ecapt.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../theme/scripts/common.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../theme/scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../theme/scripts/menuNav.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
</head>
<body id="mainbody" onresize="mainResize()" onunload="mainUnload()" onload="load()" scroll="no">
<div id="topnav" class="wrap" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0">
<div id="header">
<a href="../index.jsp">
</div>
<div id="nav">
<div class="nestedMenuDiv">
<ul id="lnkMenu0_ul">
<div class="nestedMenuDiv">
<a id="lnkMenu1" onclick="javascript:parentClick('lnkMenu1'); return false;" href="#">Wireless & Alerts</a>
</div>
<ul id="lnkMenu1_ul">
<div class="nestedMenuDiv">
<ul id="lnkMenu2_ul">
<div class="nestedMenuDiv">
<ul id="lnkMenu3_ul">
<ul id="lnkMenu0_4_ul" class="nestedlist">
<ul id="lnkMenu0_5_ul" class="nestedlist">
<ul id="lnkMenu0_12_ul" class="nestedlist">
<ul id="lnkMenu0_28_ul" class="nestedlist">
<ul id="lnkMenu2_6_ul" class="nestedlist">
</div>
<div id="toplinks2">
<div id="toplinks">
</div>
<iframe id="bodyFrame" class="mainIFrame" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="body.do?ent=ECA.Intro" scrolling="no" name="bodyFrame" style="height: 279px; width: 1366px; top: 77px; display: block;">
<iframe id="menuFrame1" class="menuCover" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="javascript:'<body>'" scrolling="no" name="menuFrame1" style="width:100%; height:0px">
<iframe id="menuFrame2" class="menuCover" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="javascript:'<body>'" scrolling="no" name="menuFrame2" style="width:100%; height:0px">
<script language="JavaScript">
</body>
</html>
</frame>
</frameset>
</html>
</frame>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: what kind of error are you getting from selenium?

Comment: I am getting no such element found error.

Comment: Share with us the code that you have tried for the click (please edit the question to add)

Comment: could the element you are tying to click be inside an iframe? if yes you must "switch" to that frame, by calling switch_to_frame(), anyway if you show some code you will get more help.

Comment: I guess you are trying to locate element by refering to  `window`, while you should use in selenium `this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow()` in order to get the working window.

Comment: I tried  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='pnmm']/ul/li[3]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a"));
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element); and this did not work either

Comment: This code worked for me finally thank you all. I was told whenever source code has driver.switchTo().frame(0);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='lnkMenu1']")).click();    
  implicitWait(10);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='entMenu1_2']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

lnkMenu2_ul is a UL object, selenium can not click on such elements, only on clickable elements.
You can add an LI under the UL and click on it